# Moving projects from eclipse workspace

Tags: java

I am using eclipse and I moved some projects(Projects with the name Mc Bot) in my workspace to another folder. However, when I open eclipse with my workspace, projects still appear like this in package explorer.

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move project folders on your hard drive and expect Eclipse to update automatically. The folders contain metafiles that Eclipse needs to properly load the workspace on startup.

1. It is better to either **rename/move** the projects **within Eclipse**.
2. Or to **remove and then re-add** them to Eclipse's project management.

However, make sure to not accidentally delete the files from disk, when removing the old project from Eclipse. There is a checkbox within the confirmation dialog that - in this case - you should not check.

Especially when you are working with a code versioning system (such as Git or SVN), it is important to rename your files and folders within the code editor. Otherwise your repository might get out of sync.

Comment: thank you. re-adding is the same thing as importing, right?

Comment: Yes. Remove in Eclipse, rename folder on disk, then import new project.

Answer (score 1):

I would just delete it here in eclipse (don't mark the checkbox to delete on disk) and then reimport it. So in this view from the screenshot just open the context-menu, say import and chose your projects again.